# sending array using MPI results in error and truncating

Tags: c++, c, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to send an array over MPI:

```
if( proc_num == 0 ){
  int serializedData[ 69];
  // fill array
  MPI_Send(serializedData, 69, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}else{
 int serializedData[ 69];
  MPI_Recv(serializedData, 69, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

However using this, i recieve error:

> *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv**   reported by process
>   [556924929,1]   **on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD**  
>   MPI_ERR_TRUNCATE: message truncated   **MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL
>   (processes in this communicator will now abort,  ***    and
>   potentially your MPI job) [warn] Epoll ADD(4) on fd 0 failed.  Old
>   events were 0; read change was 0 (none); write change was 1 (add): Bad
>   file descriptor

However when i send only for example 20 elements, it works ( but sending 50 for example results in same error).

What am i doing wrong? Why is this happening?

Thanks for help!

Comment: A runnable minimum code would be fine. Nonetheless, one thing that I could imagine, is that your compiler optimizes out the "int serializedData[69]" out to be just a pointer not allocating the full memory properly. Please test, if the error occurs, if you init each element in the recv process before passing to MPI_Recv

Comment: @fisehara: Not that compilers are perfect, but that would be absurdly bad among compiler bugs.

Comment: Please edit your question with a [MCVE]. The error is likely in the code you did not post yet.

Comment: @DavisHerring is that so? In CUDA this would be illegal, as you need the allocated pointer, its not a bug but a feature. Not sure if its the same in openmpi

Comment: @AnderBiguri: I’m not a CUDA expert, but MPI is “just” a library, so the normal language rules certainly apply.

Comment: @DavisHerring In CUDA its illegal because when you declare an array with `array[size]` it only exist withing current function scope, not globally, AFAIK.